# flask input date parsing

Tags: python, flask

I have a html form. But I am in trouble to get the date.
I try to get the day/month/year. Look the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="data-apreensao">data da apreensão</label>
        <input type="date" id="data-apreensao" name="data_apreensao" class="form-control" 
        format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
      </div>
```

and now the flask code:

```
@app.route('/cars/novo', methods=['GET','POST'])
def addCarro():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        marca = request.form['marca']
        modelo = request.form['modelo']
        placa = request.form['placa']
        motivo = request.form['motivo']
        situacao = request.form['situacao']
        # HERE I GOT THE PROBLEM
        #data_apreensao = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form['data_apreensao'], '%d, %m, %Y')
        data_apreensao = datetime.strptime(request.form['data_apreensao'], '%d, %m, %Y')
        print (data_apreensao)
        carros.append(Apreensao(marca,modelo, placa, motivo, situacao))
        return redirect('/cars')     
    return render_template('apreensaoForm.html', titulo='Nova Apreensao')
```

error:

```
ValueError
ValueError: time data '2018-01-01' does not match format '%d, %m, %Y'
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong please?

Comment: It says there, `ValueError: time data '2018-01-01' does not match format '%d, %m, %Y'`. Change your format to `'%Y-%m-%d'`, and it should work fine. Example: `datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: You're telling the user to use dashes between the numbers, but then you try to parse it with commas.

Comment: I see now. Thank you to help me

Answer (score 2):

d/m/y is what you want the user to see. But you will always receive the output in (yyyy-mm-dd) format (string). And you can parse this directly as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
the_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                     request.form['data_apreensao'],
                     '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

timeFormat year month day you only use 
'%d-%m-%Y' not use ,